# How do you create a VR game for a personal VR headset you're making?

Tags: virtual-reality, oculus

If you were to create a whole new VR headset and want to put a game on it, how would you? I know that you you could use Unity and UE4 to create games but those are for stuff like the Rift and Vive. I might be mistaken, but does anybody know the answer to my question?

Comment: Are you using any existing technology or are you making everything from scratch? If you are making all components (hardware+software) from scratch, there is no way to make game with either Unity or Unreal engine, unless you contact the companies and convince them to support your platform.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, OpenVR (used by both Unity and UE4) is an open platform. If you implement it on your side of things (i.e. the headset), you can use both editors.